# Delaying a 5 volt power off with an RC circuit

Tags: capacitor, resistors

I have a microcontroller that needs to be able to survive a power outage just long enough to shoot an email telling me that the power is out. I figured the best way of doing this would be a resistor capacitor circuit, like the one below that I made that works well, that keeps the LED lit for a second after pulling the plug.[image: RC circuit for LED off delay]

Ideally, I'd like to have something like this for my microcontroller! I just need to be able to keep it up a few seconds after the power goes out! (it instantly detects an outage)

I just have no clue what size resistor or capacitor I need, or if this is the right circuit type for the job.

specs:

Input Voltage: 5.15V

Minimum Voltage: 4V

Current draw:  600mA

Time needed: 5s minimum

I've run across many calculations, but I don't even know enough to say if I'm plugging in the right variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume for simplicity that the current is constant 600mA and the voltage is dropping from `5V` to `4V` during `5` seconds. The total charge over 5 sec that is drawn from the capacitor is `600mA * 5 = 3c`. The initial charge of a capacitor `C` is `5V * C`. The final charge is `4V * C`. The difference is `(5V-4V)C = 3`. I.e. `C=3F`. It's a damn large capacitor.

Comment: Almost 1cm in size! ^^

Comment: Ok, thank you so much! One more question, if you know. If i were to use three 1F capacitors in series on my circuit, would it be the same as using one 3F capacitor?

Comment: @Skyler Capacitors in parallel are adding up the capacitance, not in series.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. 5 Ok thank you, that's what I meant, just didn't know the lingo!